# Kendo UI Grid change row detail values from command function without detail collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with a detail template, which I wish to clear if the user clicks on the clear command in the parent row.

[image: Kendo grid with clear button]

I managed to get this to work, but as soon as I `set` the value on the `dataItem`, the row detail collapses, which causes the user to loose his place.

```
function clearDetails(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    dataItem.set("City",""); // causes row detail collapse 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
            },
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "ContactName",
            title: "Contact Name",
            width: 240
        }, {
            field: "Country",
            width: 150
        }, { command: { text: "Clear", click: clearDetails }, title: " ", width: "180px" }],
        detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#myRowDetailTemplate").html())
    })
});
```

Working example: 
https://jsbin.com/xuwakol/edit?html,js,output

Is there a way I can still clear the values in the row detail, without it collapsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this right by not using the `set` method on the dataItem. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#methods-set

I just changed the value on the dataItem, `dataItem.City ="";` and with the help of jquery selectors cleared the value of the `textarea`.

```
function clearDetails(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));   
    dataItem.City ="";
    $(e.currentTarget).closest(".k-master-row").next().find("textarea[name='City']").val("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I got around it by using the dataBinding function within the kendo grid.

Basically it checks for an item change event and will cancel the default action to close the grid. This allowed me to continue to use the set method.

**Example:**

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataBinding: function (e) {
            if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                e.preventDefault();
            }              
        },
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try. Thanks.